# Can SQL/XML UpdateGrams be run in ADO.NET?

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, adodb

The examples I find for executing a SQL/XML UpdateGram are all using ADODB.  Can the same thing be done with ADO.NET or is the older ADODB required?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sqlxml-annotated-xsd-schemas-xpath-queries/updategrams/executing-an-updategram-by-using-ado-sqlxml-4-0?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLXML is out of support, and never worked with ADO.NET.  It was superseded in SQL Server 2005 with the [built-in XML support in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

UpdateGrams are no more, but you can send an XML document to SQL Server and shred it for use in queries.

Comment: Hmmm... I work with BizTalk, where they are still alive and well (but maybe not frequently used).  And SQL/XML must be installed after BizTalk is installed.  I'm doing an XML course for Microsoft developers, and I was trying to cover all related aspects of XML and SQL (I cover OpenRowSet, For XML, XML Columns, etc...).   Where I currently work, my predecessor resorted to updategrams to send data through Host Integration Server to a DB2 running on ISeries. So I guess it's not worth discussing in my course then.

Comment: Yep.  It's legacy stuff they probably won't encounter, and definitely should not implement in new work.

Comment: BizTalk 2016 lists SQL/XML 4.0 as a prereq: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/set-up-and-install-prerequisites-for-biztalk-server-2016 
 But 2020 does not.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/set-up-and-install-prerequisites-for-biztalk-server-2020.   It is not listed as deprecated or removed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/install-and-config-guides/whats-new-in-biztalk-server-2020

Comment: What about XML Bulk Load? It says it applies even to Azure SQL. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sqlxml-annotated-xsd-schemas-xpath-queries/bulk-load-xml/introduction-to-xml-bulk-load-sqlxml-4-0?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Same.  Older products may still be using it, and it may still technically be supported, but is unlikely to get anything but a critical security fixes.  And there are better approaches for new work.